# Could not bind properties to 'FlywayProperties', AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5454d35e has not been refreshed yet

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-kafka, flyway

In our spring boot project we have postgres integration and kakfa consumer. For postgres migration we are using flyway.

When we try to start the application, we are getting the following error, we checked the information in local, flyway is working fine, only in prod it is not working, any idea will be helpful.

spring-boot - 2.4.10

spring-kafka - 2.6.10

flyway-core - 7.1.1

postgresql - 42.2.23

**Exception:**

```
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.flyway-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayProperties': Could not bind properties to 'FlywayProperties' : prefix=spring.flyway, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5454d35e has not been refreshed yet
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:92)
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:834)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:449)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolvePreparedArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:834)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:449)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$1.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:481)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:167)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:149)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findByRequestId(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not defining when should kafka consumer should start in your app, *autoStartup* value is true by default, where your Spring boot application and kafka consumer container will start in parallel.

Lets consider the case, if there is any NW latency then DB connectivity and table creation process will take sometime, where your spring boot app will take time to initialise all beans in context.Meanwhile your consumer container have started consume message already from kafka and expects the DBobjects to proceed further.

If your consumer - data flow depends on any external system, its best parctice to boot your spring app first, and then start kafka container.

you have to make autoStartup=false and user container.start() or endpointRegistry.start(),
Eg

```html
 ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
            Map<String, KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry> registry = context.getBeansOfType(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
            registry.get("org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry").start();
```